# html5 video not playing on hover in double_content box

Tags: html, video, hover

Most of my videos loop on hover, except for this one added in a double_content box:

```
<div class="content-box left">
<div class="double_content">
    <video loop class="left_double_content" preload>
        <source class="mp4-source-class" src="assets/video/movie_i_want_on_the_left.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
    <img src="assets/imgs/picture_i_want_on_the_right.png" class="right_double_content">
</div>

<p> caption box text
```

Any suggestions? Don't tear me apart, I know next to nothing about html5!  Thank you!!!

Comment: 1. Double check the url

2. make a [fiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net).... oops, link is correct now